# What is difference between those two monad transformers?

Tags: haskell, monads, transformation

I'm familiar with monads, e.g. `Reader`, `Error`, and `State`. Transformers, however, are very new to me, hence this question.

Intuitively, I can tell there is a difference between the following two monad transformers, but I can't quite pinpoint what it is...

```
ReaderT Env (ErrorT String (StateT Integer Identity)) a

ReaderT Env (StateT Integer (ErrorT String Identity)) a
```

What makes these two monad transformers different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To simplify, compare only the relevant part (which isn't trivially the same):

```
MaybeT (StateT Integer Identity) a
StateT Integer (MaybeT Identity) a
```

We know that (ignoring the `newtype` abstractions)

```
type MaybeT m a = m (Maybe a)
type StateT s m a = s -> m (a, s)
```

Hence, the two transformer stack come out to be

```
MaybeT (Λb. Integer -> (b, Integer)) a
    ≡ Integer -> (Maybe a, Integer)
```

and

```
StateT Integer (Λb. Maybe b) a
    ≡ Integer -> Maybe (a, Integer)
```

So, these aren't exactly the same, the difference being that the latter only yields the state-integer inside of the `Maybe`. This means, if the `MaybeT` is down in the stack then the computation must immediately terminate as soon as you get a `Nothing`, whereas if the `MaybeT` is used on top then the `State` can still keep on going.

This is even more drastic with `IO`: once you get an exception, you *can't* possibly continue – exceptions can only be caught in `IO` itself. This is one reason why there can be no `IOT` transformer.

Answer (score 1):

```
ReaderT Env (ErrorT String (StateT Integer Identity)) a
ReaderT Env (StateT Integer (ErrorT String Identity)) a
```

Briefly put, in the first errors only depend on the `Env` input, while the second allows errors to depend on both `Env` and the `Integer` state.